# VBA code to change color in font color selector in powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am using below code to add color in font color selection. It works fine and it add on recent. Is there way to add in top?

```
Sub tri_col()

Dim ColorList As Variant
Dim x As Integer

'Array List of RGB Color Codes to Add To Recent Colors Section (Max 10)
ColorList = Array("000,180,000", "170,230,000", "005,064,069")

'Clear Existing Recent Colors [OPTIONAL]
  ActivePresentation.ExtraColors.Clear

'Loop Through List Of RGB Codes And Add To Recent Colors
For x = LBound(ColorList) To UBound(ColorList)
    ActivePresentation.ExtraColors.Add.RGB(Left(ColorList(x), 3), Mid(ColorList(x), 5, 3), Right(ColorList(x), 3))
Next x

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Other than by defining and using a new color theme, there's no way to change the colors at the top.

Answer (score 1):

The top row displays the colors of the color theme. Here's how to save and then load a new color theme:

```
Sub SetThemeColors()
    With ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.Theme
        .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent1) = RGB(125, 125, 125)
        .ThemeColorScheme(msoThemeAccent2) = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        'Add all the other color theme colors here

        With .ThemeColorScheme
            .Save Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Colors\myNew Theme.xml"
            .Load Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\Theme Colors\myNew Theme.xml"
        End With
    End With
    ActivePresentation.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please give it am upvote.